# VBA Web scraping: Click on clickable dropdown menu (not hover)

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to do some web scraping to get a table of data.

The data is stored in Google Play Console, so you need an account to log in the website.

I managed to navigate to page I want, but table results are stored in daily metrics and this, as far as I know, cannot be changed.

This table, by default, looks like this:

[image]

I've highlighted in red color where my problem lies. I need to click on that dropdown, and change the value to *Todo" (means *All*). Activating this option allows me later on to import table will al results I need.

**IMPORTANT:** For any reason I do not know (I'm not a developer), classnames of elements are not the same if you visit the website with Google Chrome or Internet Explorer. I'm using Internet Explorer 11, so all HTML code I'm posting is because of this.

Back to dropdown menu, and using Dev Tools, I managed to get this info about that dropwdown:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="OT1ABTB-Q-a OT1ABTB-P-h OT1ABTB-Yg-a" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true"><div class="OT1ABTB-Q-a OT1ABTB-P-i">6</div><div class="OT1ABTB-Q-a OT1ABTB-P-a"></div></div>
```

Also, posting image of this part of code using Dev Tools:
[image]

And now, the relevant part of my VBA code:

```
Set objDivs = IEDoc.getElementsByClassName("OT1ABTB-N-d OT1ABTB-N-f OT1ABTB-N-a OT1ABTB-N-b")

For Each MiEle In objDivs(0).getElementsByTagName("div")

    If MiEle.className = "OT1ABTB-Q-a OT1ABTB-P-a" Then
        'code goes inside here, so I know I've grabbed the right DIV element. Just don't know what to do now
        Stop
        
        MiEle.Click 'this does not work
        
    End If
Next MiEle


Stop
```

I know I get to grab the right DIV element, but don't know how to show the dropdown menu and then select 1 option.

IF you do it manually, the dropdown menu is like this:
[image]

I need to select the option that says *Todo*.

I've noticed that when I manually click on it, HTML code changes, because property *aria-expanded* changes to `True` and then HTML code is like this:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="OT1ABTB-Q-a OT1ABTB-P-h OT1ABTB-Yg-a" role="button" aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="true" aria-activedescendant="gwt-uid-520"><div class="OT1ABTB-Q-a OT1ABTB-P-i">6</div><div class="OT1ABTB-Q-a OT1ABTB-P-a"></div></div>
```

Note there is even new property called `aria-activedescendant="gwt-uid-520"`

So I need to change only that, so table of results shows everything.

Please, if you need more HTML code or more of my VBA code, just ask for it. I've not posted all, just what I thought it's important, but if you need more info, just ask for it and I will gladly post it.

About link of website, as I said, is Google Play Console, so I'm afraid you need an account, but just in case, it's like this:

https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?&account=YOURACCOUNTNUMBERr#StatisticsPlace:p=YOURAPPNAME&statms=DAILY_USER_UNINSTALLS&statgs=DAILY&statd=OS_VERSION&statc=false&dvals=@OVERALL@&statdr=20181011-20190318&statcdr=20181011-20190318

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could use execScript to add the attribute via javascript and to change the value of the aria

Comment: Thanks @QHarr. Could you please guide me how to find what function invoke to change the value? How can I see that wth those Dev Tools?

Comment: You use setAttribute to change it and removeAttribute to remove. These are javascript functions applied with ie.document.parentWindow.execScript "document.querySelector('mySelector').setAttribute('myattribute','myNewValue');" etc

Comment: You should seriously consider using python.  It will be *much* easier to implement and if you have gotten this far using VBA, it won't be hard to rewrite your code in python.

Comment: @Jane thx for your suggestion, but I'm afraid I have no idea of python. I'm just a man of Excel and VBA medium level. No other languages/knowledge. (not even HTML/Javascript or whatever lol). Anyways, learning Python is on *my to-do list*.

Comment: @QHarr nice! I'll try it and let you know asap. Thanks!!!

Comment: Don't hold out much hope tbh. I wish I could test properly.